# Is there an Excel formula where I can ignore the first few characters of a file name?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rename, filenames

I want to ask if it is possible for there to be a Excel formula (or perhaps a macro) which can remove the first few characters of a file name (however, the number of characters varies...see below). I have limited experience with VBA although in python or java, I could see how a while loop may be used.

For example, some of the file names I am using include (where XXXX is the name of the file that I want to keep):

S00.002-2-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

S05.051[4]-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

S03.025[P4]-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

12345-S01.132[CC]-XXXXXXXXXXX

Additionally, the file names represented by the XXXXXXX always start with a letter so that would be when the loop would terminate (or rather, the loop would terminate after the '-' before the file name).

As you can see, the file names vary due to the different naming conventions that are used, which means that a 'for' loop is probably not preferable.

As of right now, I have been mainly using the MID() formula on Excel (i.e.=MID(B3,16,50)) which requires me to change the middle number of the formula every time there is a change in the naming convention (and thus uses up a lot of time).

Answer (score 0):

=MID([Cell],FIND("-",[Cell])+1,256) will extract all text after the delimiter.

What are you wanting to do with the file name?

Comment: I tried using that, but it only filters the text up until the first "-". In some cases, the file names have multiple "-" before the actual name that I want to keep.

I need to extract file names for filing purposes, and also for using in any lists that may be given out to others.

Comment: Then use: =RIGHT([Cell], LEN([Cell]-SEARCH("#", SUBSTITUTE([Cell], "-", "#", LEN([Cell])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([Cell], "-", "")))))